# Spring Boot- Itext - Error - Worker of type PTagWorker unable to process DivTagWorker

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

While using IText to process HTML to create a PDF file I get the following error in the logger:

```
ERROR 9260 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.i.h.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor   : Worker of type com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.PTagWorker unable to process com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.DivTagWorker
```

The error is not a typical stack trace error, just a single in the logger. It also doesn't stop execution, and a PDF is generated eventually. Both my HTML and PDF files are rather large, so it's difficult to check piece by piece, but a quick look doesn't seem to show any actual errors in the target file.

Is there a specific reason why this error happens/is shown? And will it eventually prevent a PDF file from being generated?

(All of this is happening in the context of a Spring Boot application. I don't know if that might be relevant).

Comment: Actually the message you posted does not explicitly state an error. Probably it's a debugging output that for some reason has become too visible...

Comment: My bad, I didn't copy the whole thing at first.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your HTML file is large, you don't have to check piece by piece and you can make use of binary search approach instead - split your document into two more or less equal pieces and try with the first half of the file, and if the problem reproduces split it further down into two pieces. If the problem does not reproduce for the first half of the file then it should reproduce for the second half of the file and you will continue to split the file pieces into two smaller ones until the file is small enough to see the problem.

As `pdfHTML` add-on is open source, you can debug the source of the problem instead - just go to the source of `PTagWorker#processTagChild` and hit the breakpoint at the `return false;` line (see [source on GitHub](https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml/blob/d6a59bc4246d626cf0059f581673b9ec381a3caf/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/attach/impl/tags/PTagWorker.java#L159)) - if the result if `false` then the error in question is logged. From there you will be able to better see the context of the elements triggering the log error by inspecting the invocation one level down the call stack in `DefaultHtmlProcessor#visit` and namely `element` local variable that corresponds to an HTML element.

So specific reason can be deducted by using on of the approaches presented above - it can be a bug/missing feature in pdfHTML, or the fact that a block level element is added to a paragraph level element and that was not normalized automatically.

This log error will by itself not prevent a PDF file from being generated, but it can result in some content missing in the resultant PDF, so it it important to find the root cause.